# Joining two different tables in the Join clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have three tables Table A, Table B, and Table C.

```
Table A:AId, id, state, prop_id, category
Table B:BId, id, state, prop_id, MainProductid, price
Table C:CId, id, state, category, mainproductid, subProductid, price
```

```
Example Data:
Aid id  prop_id category        
1   1   SH      SCA500      
2   1   PH      SCA500      
3   1   PK      SCA500      
4   1   LP      SCB300      
5   1   LQ      SCB300      
                    
Bid id  prop_id mainProductId   price   
1   1   SH      Base            30  
2   1   SH      BasePlus        40  
3   1   PH      Base            30  
4   1   PH      BasePlus        50  
5   1   LQ      Base            35  
                    
Cid id  category    mainProductId   subProductid    price
1   1   SCA500      Base            Lower Margin    25
2   1   SCB300      Base            Lower Margin    30
3   1   SCA500      BasePlus        Upper Margin    25
4   1   SCB300      BasePlus        Upper Margin    30

declare  @TableA table(Aid int, id int, prop_id varchar(100), category varchar(100))
declare  @TableB table(Bid int, id int, prop_id varchar(100), mainProductId varchar(100), price int) 
declare @TableC table(Cid int, id int, Category varchar(100), mainProductId varchar(100), subProductid varchar(100), price int)

Insert into @tableA values (1,1,'SH','SCA500'), (2,1,'PH','SCA500'),(3,1,'PK','SCA500'),(4,1,'LP','SCB300'),(5,1,'LQ','SCB300')
                     
Insert Into @tableB values (1,1,'SH','Base',30),(2,1,'SH','BasePlus',40),(3,1,'PH','Base',30),(4,1,'PH','BasePlus',50),(5,1,'LQ','Base',35)
                                                                               
Insert into @tableC values (1,1,'SCA500','Base','Lower Margin',25),(2,1,'SCB300','Base','Lower Margin',30),(3,1,'SCA500','BasePlus','Upper Margin',25),(4,1,'SCB300','BasePlus','Upper Margin',30)
```

Expected result:

```
id  prop_id category    mainproductid   mainPrice   SubProductId    subPrice
1   SH      SCA500      Base            30          Lower Margin    25
1   SH      SCA500      Baseplus        40          Upper Margin    25
1   PH      SCA500      Base            30          Lower Margin    25
1   PH      SCA500      Baseplus        50          Upper Margin    25
1   LQ      SCA500      Baseplus        35          Lower Margin    30
```

A category can have multiple prop_ids.
I have to get all the main products, their sub products and their price.
The query below is how I have to do it.

```
Select a.id,a.prop_id,a.category,b.mainProductId, b.price 'mainPrice',c.subproductid,c.price 'subPrice'
From TableA a
Join TableB b
On a.id = b.id
And a.prop_id = b.prop_id
Join TableC c
On b.id = c.id
And b.mainproductid = c.mainProductid
And a.category = c.category
```

If we had prop_id in Table C then I would not need the extra join condition to Table A in the last clause. Is this good db design?
What are the disadvantages of joining to multiple tables in the join clause? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Luuk. I apologize that I did not elaborate the question. In order to join tableC to table B, I have to join it to table A as well because of how the db was designed. I'll update the question for better understanding.

Comment: If you say, after the (inner) join, `a.id = b.id` then every a.id is equal to b.id, and the same is true for a.id and c.id.   The conclusion can be drawn that is is pretty useless to specify `b.id=c.id`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question. It might give you more clarity on what i'm asking.

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would help to clarify what you are asking

Comment: thanks, Peter! I have updated the data.

Comment: Q: "Is this good db design? A: NO     Q: "What are the disadvantages of joining to multiple tables in the join clause?"  A:  On SO it is a rule that your should only ask 1 question at a time and, in order to answer this second question, one has to know which indexes are defined in the tables (and currently you have shown no index definitions.

Comment: Also, if you only have 5 records in a table, then any (read ANY) DB design can be called 'good'.

Comment: Indexes on searched fields are good, generally. Even indexes have their cost, I wouldn't say having that one field in table c would make a big difference in calling this setup good, there are other questions to answer...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need TableA.

```
SELECT B.prop_id
, B.mainProductId
, B.price AS mainPrice   
, C.Category
, C.subProductid
, C.price AS subPrice
FROM [dbo].[TableB] B
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableC] C ON B.mainProductId = C.mainProductId
```